# any distinction between $[1, \infty)$ and $[1, \infty]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Considering the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $(0, 1]$, how would you notate the range of values that $f(x)$ takes on?  It is:

- finite at every point in $(0, 1]$
- unbounded in this interval

Should the notation be $f(x) \in [1, \infty)$?

Is there any distinction between $[1, \infty)$ and $[1, \infty]$?

Edit for clarity:

Is there a clean way to notate the distinction between:

- "range of $\frac{1}{x}, x \in [0, 1]$"
- "range of $\frac{1}{x}, x \in (0, 1]$"

Comment: $[1,\infty) = \{x~:~x\in\Bbb R, x\geq 1\}$.  Meanwhile $[1,\infty] = [1,\infty)\cup \{\infty\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Formally speaking, $\infty$ is not a real number, so if your function is defined on reals, $[1,\infty]$ is meaningless and in some sense, oxymoronic.

Sometimes it is interesting to expand the reals, defining a new set $\bar{R} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$, which allows to map $1/0 = \infty$, for example, and makes the set closed under taking limits which would ordinarily diverge. There, such notation as $[1,\infty]$ would be well-defined.

Comment: Members of $\bar{R}$ are called extended real numbers.

Comment: hmm.  i take your point.  So, then, how would you notate the range of $f(x), x \in [0, 1]$ vs $f(x), x \in (0, 1]$ to highlight the fact that one includes an undefined value and the other does not?

Comment: @HenryBigelow notation does this for you, since $[0,1] - (0,1] = \{0\}$. If you are talking about the range of $f(x)=1/x$, then if you define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f(0)$ is undefined and hence $x=0$ does not contribute to the range of $f$. When $f$ is defined to map $\bar{R} \to \bar{R}$, it's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\infty$ is not attained by your function the correct range is $[0,\infty)$

$[0, \infty]$ does not make sense in real numbers because $\infty $ is not a real number.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is excluding the extended real number $\infty$ as a possible value of $f(x)$. Since $0\not\in(0,\,1]$, $[1,\,\infty)$ is correct.